# Is using a DERATE for Takeoff actually reducing the power of the engine?

Tags: takeoff, boeing-737

When one chooses a DERATE for takeoff (TO-1 or TO-2 in the case of a B737), does the system **actually** reduce the available thrust of the engines, or is it computing a N1 that corresponds to the reduced (de-rated) thrust?

Referring to a B737NG for example, does a setting of "TO 89%" produce the same thrust as a TO-1 or TO-2 with the same N1 of 89%?

Comment: Do you want a general answer or a 737 specific answer?

Comment: A specific B737 answer would serve fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

I cant' give you a 737 specific answer, but how DERATE or Flex Thrust is applied generally depends on whether the engine is FADEC or not.

If a non-FADEC, it's just an FMS computed bug target setting on the N1 indicators and you move the thrust levers as required to match N1 to the bug. So it's still the pilot actually setting thrust to a lower computer-provided target than normal (if the airplane has an autothrottle system, it's the autopilot doing that job on behalf of the pilot through thrust lever servos).

If FADEC, where you (or an autothrottle system) just move the thrust levers until they click into a detent of some sort for takeoff and let the FADEC computers directly control the engines to achieve a computed N1 setting, it's the computers controlling the engines in accordance with your thrust rating selection when you ask for TO thrust.  So in that case it's the pilot telling the computers what he/she wants, and the computers do the actual work.

Comment: Understood, this is how I thought it works. But my specific question was and is whether the same N1 setting produces different thrust depending on whether TO (26k), TO-1 (24k derate) or TO-2 (22k derate) has been selected. Forgetting about Assumed Temperature for this example.

Comment: No on a turbofan the N1 value is the primary indication of thrust and if thrust is reduced, the N1 value, the fan being the primary thrust source, will be lower.  Turbofans are just turboprops with fixed pitch many-bladed propellers (and even "propeller" reduction gearboxes on the newest ones), and like an O-200 with a fixed pitch prop, fan rpm is the primary power indicator.

Comment: The 737 is somewhere in between the non-FADEC and the FADEC cases you mentioned. It has EEC, but no detents for the thrust levers. The autothrottle servos set the exact thrust lever position for you on takeoff, but the pilots could overwrite it by pushing the levers further forwards.

Comment: @Bianfable i made some edits in response to your comment but you should perhaps provide that as an answer no?

Comment: @JohnK Thanks, that looks fine. I didn't answer because I wasn't really sure what OP wanted to know. I think your first comment actually answers what they wanted to know.

Comment: I am still not clear: My question is not about HOW to set TO thrust. Let me try and rephrase what I am looking for: Referring to the B737, does an FMC setting of TO (26k) and 89% N1 produces exactly the same Thrust with say a TO-1 (24k) or TO-2 (22k) and 89% N1? In other words, if the N1 is set to 89% in all cases, selecting TO (no derate), TO-1 (24k derate) or TO-2 (22k derate) makes no difference if it results in the same N1? Or Does the EEC actually derate the engines, so at the *same* 89% N1 it produces less thrust if TO-1 or TO-2 are selected?

Comment: Well that depends on what actual ran rpm 100% represents. If the derate modes reduce the fan speed that represents 100% N1 to be in line with 22/24K, then 89% is a thrust reduction as well, being 89% of the reduced 100% thrust level. So if normal 100% max thrust represents a fan rpm of, say, 4800, and 24K is 4400 rpm, then 89% also represents 89% of 4800 or 89% of 4400. In any case for non-FADEC the EEC just trims the fuel schedule electronically a little bit above the hydro-mech schedule, so I think it would still just be target indications that change. You need a 737 guy to answer this one.

Comment: What you write makes sense. I wish a 737 guy steps in and tells me how it works in the B737